# Is CToolBar docking or floating?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mfc, dock, docking

Is there any method in MFC to find out "Is CToolBar docking or floating?". In my program I need to knew it exactly.

I don't want to use such code:

```
void MyCToolBAR:: ...
{
   RECT rc; 
   GetClientRect(&rc);
}
```

For example. If bar we will get

(0,0) - leftTop angle,

(x,y) - data.

That is mean: BAR IS PROBABLY DOCKED.

Thanks for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `GetBarStyle()` and checking for `CBRS_FLOATING` flag. Other flags that could be set are shown in help file for `CToolBar::Create()`.